# Bitwise operations in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Reading an article about Angular's change detection mechanism I encountered this typescript code:

```
detach(): void { this._view.state &= ~ViewState.ChecksEnabled; }
```

I've been trying to wrap my head around that line of code.

I know the `~` trick and how it's used with `indexOf()`. I find it hard to understand in terms of bits but remembering that it can be replaced with `-(x+1)` thus making only -1 falsy makes it easier.

It seems `ViewState.ChecksEnabled` is a boolean so `~ViewState.ChecksEnabled` gives -(0 + 1) or -(1 + 1)

Then with the `&=` bitwise assignment (?) we get

```
this._view.state = this._view.state & -1; // or -2
```

What's the trick here?

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6b79ab5abec8b5a4b43d563ce65f032990b3e3bc/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L346

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should see this as binary calculus.

let's assume the `_view.state` is equal to 1, and the `ViewState.ChecksEnabled` is equal to 1.

We have two bitwise operators :

- `&` will perform an AND operation on corresponding bits equal to 1
- `~` will invert the bits

So with the "rewrite" of the operation, we have :

```
var = 1 & ~ 1
```

We apply the tilde :

```
var = 1 & 0
```

Then the AND :

```
var = 0
```

Which would give a plain zero. If you apply this with `_view.state` equal to 0, that would give :

```
var = 0 & ~1 = 0 & 0 = 0
```

When you use 0, 0 :

```
var = 0 & ~0 = 0 & 1 = 0
```

And 1, 0 :

```
var = 1 & ~0 = 1 & 1 = 1
```

So to sum up :

```
0, 0 → 0
0, 1 → 0
1, 0 → 1
1, 1 → 0
```

You can also create a sandbox to test that for several numbers :

```js
for (const i of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) {
  for (const j of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) {
    console.log(`${i} & ~${j} = ${ i & ~j }`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details! Does it mean view.state &= ~ViewState.ChecksEnable gives the same result as view.state ^= ViewState.ChecksEnable ?

Comment: @gyc [Just tested](https://jsfiddle.net/bo52tdfj/) and it doesn't. I explained with examples without testing, I should change my answer to reflect that !